# Accessing data inside of constructor javascript not working

Tags: javascript, class

I am having issues when trying to create a function inside of a constructor.  The function doesn't seem to understand variables that are also initialized inside of the constructor.

I need the variables and functions inside of the class.

Here is some sample code

```
class dLoginPage { 
  constructor() {   
    this.Username     = Aliases.browser.page_General_Login.formLoginform.textboxUsernameinput;
    this.Password     = Aliases.browser.page_General_Login.formLoginform.passwordboxPasswordinput;
    this.SubmitButton = Aliases.browser.page_General_Login.formLoginform.submitbuttonLogin;

    this.Login = function() {
      this.Username.SetText("admin");
      this.Password.SetText("admin");
      this.SubmitButton.ClickButton();
    }
  }
}

module.exports = dLoginPage;
```

When I try running the login function, it states that username and password and submitbutton have not been initialized.  But if i take the login function outside of the class, everything works.  But i need the function inside of the class.

Comment: why do you want to create function in the constructor?

Comment: I need to access the class from another class. 

For example I have a class called GeneralModule

I want the ability to go

GeneralModule.LoginPage.Login

Comment: Why is it that you are using this.Login

Comment: Because if i don't i get a runtime error.
ReferenceError: Login is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply add the function as a method to your class?

Constructor functions didn't support this, but ES6 classes do.

```
class dLoginPage {
  constructor() {
    this.Username = Aliases.browser.page_General_Login.formLoginform.textboxUsernameinput;
    this.Password = Aliases.browser.page_General_Login.formLoginform.passwordboxPasswordinput;
    this.SubmitButton = Aliases.browser.page_General_Login.formLoginform.submitbuttonLogin;
  }

  Login() {
    this.Username.SetText("admin");
    this.Password.SetText("admin");
    this.SubmitButton.ClickButton();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use arrow function

```
this.Login = ()=> {
  this.Username.SetText("admin");
  this.Password.SetText("admin");
  this.SubmitButton.ClickButton();
}
```